# Arrow cuts symbol when using the xymatrix command

Tags: xy-pic

I would like to know the following:

Using xy-pic, how can I avoid that in the diagram below the one arrow's tail cuts the letter I? Is there a command in xy-pic to shorten arrows?

Thanks for the help.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{eufrak}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[pdftex]{color}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[arrow, matrix, curve]{xy}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

$\xymatrix@1{I\ar[r] \ar@{>->}[d]_f & K\otimes_R M \ar@{-->}[dl]\\ M^F & }$ 

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a custom `\mystrut` before the `I`, in this case a `\strut` scaled by 1.3.  However, the custom strut could consist of a simple `\rule[depth]{0pt}{height}` of the desired dimensions.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{eufrak}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[pdftex]{color}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[arrow, matrix, curve]{xy}
\usepackage{multirow}
\def\mystrut{\scalebox{1.3}{\strut}}
\begin{document}

$\xymatrix@1{\mystrut I\ar[r] \ar@{>->}[d]_f & K\otimes_R M \ar@{-->}[dl]\\ M^F & }$ 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Arrows with a tail are a big problem with Xy-pic, because the tail isn't taken into account for the arrow width.

A source for the overlapping is the suffix `@1` that squeezes the diagram. Exercise 14 in the manual gives a workaround:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[arrow, matrix, curve,cmtip]{xy}

\newdir{ >}{{}*!/-8pt/@{>}} % exercise 14

\begin{document}

$\xymatrix@1{
  I\ar[r] \ar@{ >->}[d]_f & K\otimes_R M \ar@{-->}[dl]\\
  M^F
}$

\bigskip

$\xymatrix{
  I\ar[r] \ar@{ >->}[d]_f & K\otimes_R M \ar@{-->}[dl]\\
  M^F
}$

\end{document}
```

Note the difference when `@1` is omitted. I used `cmtip`, because I can't stand the default style.

[image]

Here's the same with `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

$\begin{tikzcd}
  I\arrow{r}{} \arrow[swap,rightarrowtail]{d}{f} & K\otimes_R M \arrow[dash pattern=on 4pt off 3pt]{dl} \\
  M^F
\end{tikzcd}$

\end{document}
```

[image]