# xymatrix/diagram: changing arrow tips/tails with spacing

Tags: diagrams, arrows, xymatrix

I want to typeset two different kinds of arrows, as in

```
\[
\xymatrix{ 
  \cdot \ar@{{(}{-}{>}}[r]^a & \cdot \\
  \cdot \ar@{{)}{-}{>}}[r]^a & \cdot 
}
\]
```

which produces

[image: Custom arrow tail alignment]

Object alignment is fine, of course, but I want the *arrows* to have the same length, too. That is, the left of ")" (red) should be vertically aligned to the left of "(" (green).

Does anybody know how to do it?

I know there are "similar", well-aligned tips and tails such as ^c and many others, and I also know, that Ti*k*Z is said to offer an easier way of redefining arrow tips. 
Sadly, it *must* be a `xymatrix` and it must be "(" and ")".

Any suggestion greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1):

Use a workaround similar to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/177255/4427

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}

\newdir{ )}{{}*!/-0.6em/@{)}} % exercise 14

\begin{document}

\[
\xymatrix{
  \cdot \ar@{(->}[r]^a & \cdot \\
  \cdot \ar@{ )->}[r]^a & \cdot
}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]